# What is difference between single view application and blank app xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I see two project templation `single view application` and `blank app` in Visual Studio 2017. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use blank app if you want to design custom views using the native layouts for different platforms. Use single view application if you want your view to be shared across different platforms. You have the flexibility to use both approach in your project anyway. For example you can use `Xamarin.forms` for some data driven views and combine that with some native views for platform specific interactions.

If you want a quick development cycle avoid using blank apps, single view application has the benefit of shared code across all the projects and UI is created once and used across all the platforms.